# String checking for a while loop not working correctly

Tags: java, loops

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(system.in);
String input = new String();

while(!input.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) {
input = scanner.nextLine();
}
```

Why is this not working? The loop lasts forever. I have used this method a million times before and now it wont work.

EDIT**

Okay I am using JGrasp (as this is what my professor wants us to use) 
and when I tried this in netbeans it worked fine...

EDIT2**

First of all I am not sure whether or not this is the problem but in my code I had something like this towards the beginning of main
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
And later on something like this
    scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
and that is where the previous code snippet starts off. So first of all I changed this by having main call a new method for the area where I needed the while loop with string checking. And I also reformatted the loop:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = new String();

    while(!input.contains("stop")) {
        System.out.print("Enter an option: ");
        input = scanner.nextLine();
    }
```

And now it works fine.

EDIT3**

So I tried the original format inside the new method and it also works perfectly. I believe now that it has something to do with how I had a scanner for the file and then reused that reference for a new scanner object with System.in. I am not 100% on that, but moving the while loop to a method of its own and not keeping it in main worked, so I feel like it has something to do with that.

Comment: The input line has to precisely equal "stop".  It can't have an extra tab, space, non-printable unicode character, or anything else.

Comment: Just guessing - input.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("stop")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should be checking that the Scanner has something left to parse?

```
while(scanner.hasNextLine() && !input.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) {
    input = scanner.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: This is actually input by the user and not a file or anything, so the scanner would always have something left to parse...to the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Code is working fine:
Except an **compilation** error i.e please use `System.in` instead of `system.in`

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = new String();

while(!input.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) {
    input = scanner.nextLine();
}
```